# How does Wordpress insert Paragraphs in posts

Tags: php, functions

So when looking at the html-view in the editor there is no `<p>` tags, when a view the post every line break is surrounded with a `<p>`. How?

Comment: It adds them on display.. it's one of several filters that are ran over the content when it is prepared for display.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realised this. That would rather inefficient to me. I would have thought the opposite would be better: remove them on edit. Not that it matters really I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is run through the wpautop filter (there's a lot about that on Google).